# PyCharm IDE and run.bat file runs all the tests instead specified number

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

**Issue :**  PyCharm IDE and run.bat file runs all the tests instead specified number

Here is the command i have used to run the tests.

pabot  --processes 1 --outputdir Results --report AutoReport.html TestCases*.robot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tags] to specify the tests you want to run.
Check this for more info https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases

Then you can run by adding `-i <tags>`

Assuming you have this test case

```
Test Case1
    [Tags]  test1
    Do something ...

Test Case2
    [Tags]  test2
    Do something ...

Test Case3
    [Tags]  test3
    Do something ...
```

To execute specific test case, you can use this in pabot

```
pabot -i test1 -i test2 -i test3 --processes 1 --outputdir Results --report AutoReport.html TestCases
```

Comment: Let me put it this way.I have written test cases in Page Object Model.Lets say I have 3 test cases per page LoginTest.robot,RegistrationTest.robot and FormSubmissionTest.robot under the TestCases folder now I want to run 2 TestCases by specifying name of file . As I said if I specify number it does matter runs all 3 tests under the TestCases folder

Comment: I got your point, now just add "--testlevelsplit" on your pabot. Then it will go like this. "pabot --testlevelsplit --processes 1 ..."